# why SaveChanges returned 2 instead of 1 since I used FirstOrDefault()

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

in the following code I want to Update record As you see SaveChanges() call when I get the First 'q'. but after running the code and get the first and only record for the one to Update, I get the success returned 2. the problem is after saveChanges I have 2 records in Sal Table. what should I write for define q until I get int success just 1. and update clearly.

```
     public static bool UpdateUser(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                
                var q = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == user.UserName).**FirstOrDefault**();

                if (q != null)
                {
                    q.Password = user.Password;
                    db.Users.Update(user);
                    int *success* = db.SaveChanges();
                    if (success == 1)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;

                    }
                   
                }
                return false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

the problem, is about *SaveChanges* returned 2 instead of 1 since I used *FirstOrDefault()*

Comment: You are updating two entities, user and q ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using "Connected scenario" of EF in your code.
in this case dbset that you fetching data from, tracking and EF listening to your changes for the data getting from dbset, then, after any changes to this datas when you using "SaveChanges" update them.

for resolve that You can use db.User.AsNoTracking().... to say to EF that i not needed to track dbset!